# data appear undefined in my component, but it normally appears inside the mapStateToProps function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am making a basic Songs select app using react and redux, but I have some problems.
In the mapStateToProps() function in my Songlist Component, the state argument, passed, usually gets a value
But when I try to Log Props in Component I get a value of undefined

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import reducers from './reducers'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**Action**

```
export const selectSong = (song) => {

    return {
        type: 'SELECT_SONG',
        payload: song
    }
}
```

**Reducers**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
const songReducer=()=>{
    return [
        {title: 'El Sawarekh ft. Zuksh & Shehta Karika – Ekhwaty' ,duration:'3:50'},
        {title: 'Sherine – Masha’er' ,duration:'4:00'},
        {title: 'Hala Al Turk – Zahgana' ,duration:'2:54'},
        {title: 'Hamza Namira – Dari Ya Alby' ,duration:'5:00'},
    ]
}

const selectedSongReducer=(selectedSong=null,action)=>{
    if(action.type==='SELECT_SONG'){
        return action.payload
    }
    return selectedSong
}

export default combineReducers({
    song:songReducer,
    selectedSong:selectedSongReducer
})
```

**SongList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
class SongList extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)   //First console  => undefined
        return (
            <div>SongList</div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps =state=>{
    console.log(state)              //Second console => Array(4)
    return {songs: state.songs}
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SongList)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproductible example. I don't see where SongList is called, with what props. I don't know Redux, but by any chance, you passed `song` without `s` inside `combineReducers`, maybe that is related.

Comment: @Ambroise Rabier
 Yes, that was the problem. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Happy to hear your issue is fixed. I have made a proper answer, so that you can mark it as accepted answer. This will also show to Stackoverflow community that this question has been answered and need less or none more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where SongList is called, with what props. I don't know Redux, but by any chance, you passed song without s inside combineReducers, maybe that is related.